# C# FileBrowserDialog and a write-protected Folder

Tags: c#, file

A user should create a folder where the application creates a xml file. Now I'm facing the problem that this folder is write-protected. So the application cannot write the xml file in this folder. I don't know how to approach this.

```
 private void buttonCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderElg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBoxPath.Text = folderElg.SelectedPath;
            userConfigurePath = folderElg.SelectedPath;
        }
        XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode myRoot;                               
        myRoot = config.CreateElement("Tool");    
        config.AppendChild(myRoot);                        
        config.Save(@userConfigurePath);

    }
```

Comment: Give write rights to this folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write to write-protected folder. The only way you can handle this is to catch exception and display message. For example like this:

```
try
{
   config.Save(@userConfigurePath);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Sorry there was en error with writing file. Try different location");
}
```

Comment: The Problem is the user creates the folder himself. Is there any possibility that he creates the folder with write rights?

Comment: How he creates this folder? There is an option in NTFS rights that you can create folder but cannot create files.

Comment: private FolderBrowserDialog folderElg = new FolderBrowserDialog();

Comment: And one more question what type is: `folderElg` is it `FileBrowserDialog` or `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Comment: You should use `FileBrowserDialog` because user is trying save file as folder, what gives him an error

Comment: hm sry i don't understand it. So the user creates/chooses with the FolderBrowseDialog a folder. Then the application creates the xml. So do I must use the savedialog for the xml file?

Comment: But in `@userConfigurePath` you have path to folder not to file

Comment: yes because i want to save this file in this folder. The file doesn't exists before the folder is created/choosen

Comment: So you can change you code like this: `config.Save(@userConfigurePath+"\\file.xml");`